# Can I always use .map even if .forEach looks more logical in come circumstances?

Tags: javascript

I see `.map()` and `.forEach()` work similar in most cases, though I know `.map()` is more suitable for returning some result based on transforming input, and `.forEach()` is just to iterate over items and apply some operation on each.

I know it suits well in this case:

```
var customersList = dataItems.map(function (item) {
    return item.isCustomer
})
```

But I find it easier to just throw `.forEach()` out of my head and just use `.map()` in all my code. Would it be conceptually correct to use `.map()` in a case like this?

```
domElements.map(function (el) {
    if (el.enabled) {
        el.show()
    } else {
        el.hide()
    }
})
```

Comment: do nout use `map`, because of the overhead to store a temp array with all `undefined` items, if you do not need it.

Comment: `forEach` operates on the original array elements. If you don't fear mutations, you can use it whenever you want.

Comment: You should use what suits the situation the best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can. But you shouldn't.

It's minor performance hit, but more importantly it's also a maintenance burden. If I had to come along and maintain your code, I would assume something was wrong, or would have to take longer looking at that piece of code to gauge the intent. Why `map` there? Is it supposed to return something? Am I not understanding correctly?

This is a much more important concern than performance.

Answer (score 0):

As someone pointed out in the comments, map() will be less performant because it returns a new array. A function that doesn't explicitly return anything actually returns undefined, so your map will return an array of undefineds with the same number of elements as the original array.

If you don't want to remember or google up all those methods every time you need to iterate an array, just stick to the good old for loop which is way faster anyway. If you care about performance you can write something like:

```
for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++)
```

which is almost as fast as a backwards loop.